# how to disable copy file on drag-and-drop

Tags: emacs

According to a [doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html)

> Emacs supports “drag and drop”: dropping a file into an ordinary Emacs window visits the file using that window. As an exception, dropping a file into a window displaying a Dired buffer moves or copies the file into the displayed directory.

How can I disable move or copy of a file in a dired mode so that emacs would visit the file in any mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `dired-dnd-protocol-alist` to `nil`.

```
(setq dired-dnd-protocol-alist nil)
```

...or use `M-x customize` to do it.